# Electron-react set file download path

Tags: reactjs, file, path, electron

I'm creating an application with electron and reactjs. In that application I want to create a component for the user to chose the file download path. Is it possible with react and how can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily like the following:

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.handleSetDownloadPath}>Set Download Path</button>
```

And the `handleSetDownloadPath` method is:

```
import { remote } from "electron";

...

handleSetDownloadPath = () => {
    remote.dialog.showOpenDialog(
      {
        properties: ["openDirectory"]
      },
      files => {
        if (files) {
          this.setState({
            downloadPath: files[0]
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };
```